# Error on Fetching from API (SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data)

Tags: javascript, json, deployment, fetch-api

I'm trying to make a recipe app, and I am trying to fetch recipes from a public API named "themealdb". I made a function named `getRandomMeal(`) as you can see in my code which will fetch it from the API but I am getting this error. I am new to web developing. Here's my JavaScript code :

```js
getRandomMeal();

async function getRandomMeal() {
  const resp = await fetch("www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php");
  const randomMeal = await resp.json();

  console.log(randomMeal);
}

async function getMealByawaitId(Id) {
  const meal = await fetch(
    "www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/lookup.php?i=" + id
  );
}

async function getMealBySearch(term) {
  const meals = await fetch(
    "www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=" + term
  );
}
```

So, can you take a look at my code and tell me what am I doing wrong or whats the reason behind this error and how should i fix this?

Comment: Just make sure you are getting api response in a correct json format. otherwise it will give you that error.

Comment: The API you are calling is not returning JSON. You can use the browser "Network" developer tool to look at the actual response body.

Comment: It works if you add `https://` to the start of the URL (and are using a development server).